# But that day is never today

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from an article in Financial Times. The title is Not All Successful Entrepreneurs Crave the Limelight.

A friend who works in publishing always jokes that one day, his industry will recognise that the link between followers on Twitter and Instagram and book sales is by no means a straightforward one — “***but that day is never today***”.

Does the bolded sentence mean the publishing industry will never recognize or will not recognize that anytime soon?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it means it is not recognizing it presently or now.

Comment: I would suggest that it means exactly what you say. He says that **one day** it will happen, but somehow that day never seems to arrive.